# How to configure NGINX not to cache specific URL?

Tags: nginx, cache-control

I have a NGINX server as front-end cache server and I'd like to disable cache on specific urls.

Here is the configuration on NGINX:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m  inactive=120m max_size=1000m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";

server {
  listen       10.0.0.45:80 default_server;
  server_name  proxy2.jjd;
  include      /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
  location / {

    client_max_body_size 20m;
    proxy_cache my_zone;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;

    proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;

    add_header      X-Proxy-Cache-NGINX $upstream_cache_status;
    add_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header      Cache-Control "public";
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;

    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout    90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect        off;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide your nginx config, but it usually involves the `proxy_cache_bypass` directive.

Comment: Hi, updated the question. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As I get it, you just need a nested `location` with a single string `proxy_cache off;` inside to disable caching for nested URLs. Like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_cache my_zone;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;
    // other stuff related to proxying or other processing
    location /do/not/cache/this/url/ {
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following location to avoid an url:

```
location ^~ /your-url/ {
    add_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;

    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout    90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect        off;
}
```

It just assigns this location to the proxy and doesn't enable caching for it.

Answer (score -2):

you can just specify location  do proxy_pass only for disable cache

location /will/not/cache {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    ..set_header ..
}

Comment: Thank you. Should I put that statement below location / {} or above? Also the location is on remote vhost and its url is like that http://example.com/default/files/public/xx and I am not sure how to put that into location /will/not/cache